# Office GraphAPI SMTP - Need help building C# code for .netcore to send email as:

Tags: c#

Very new to this and need help creating C# code that utilizes Microsoft Graph API to create a token and send an email as. We have webapps that use basic authentication currently and I would like to switch them to using modern authentication. I have created an application in azure and gotten to the part where I need to create an access token but am not sure how to write the code to do so.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/legacy-protocols/how-to-authenticate-an-imap-pop-smtp-application-by-using-oauth#authenticate-connection-requests

Below is some powershell/json that I tried just to prove out the concept to myself in something somewhat familiar. This one comes up with an auth denied error.

```
# Variables for the environment
$clientId = "myidishere"
$clientSecret = "ssshhhitsAsecret"
$RedirectURI = "https://test.onmicrosoft.com"
$resource = "https://graph.microsoft.com"
$useremail = "email@mail.com"

   Add-Type -AssemblyName system.web
#encoded Variables for the oauth string. 
$clientIDEncoded = [Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode($clientid)
$clientSecretEncoded = [Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode($clientSecret)
$redirectUriEncoded =  [Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode($redirectUri)
$resourceEncoded = [Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode($resource)

# Get oauth2 Code
$url = ('https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&redirect_uri={0}&client_id={1}&resource={2}&prompt=admin_consent&login_hint={3}' -f $redirectUriEncoded, $clientIDEncoded, $resourceEncoded, $useremail)

# Pops a window to Authenticate to Microsoft Online.
$form = New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.Form -Property @{Width=420;Height=600}
$web  = New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser -Property @{Width=420;Height=600;Url=$url}
$DocComp  = {$script:uri = $web.Url.AbsoluteUri; if ($script:uri -match "error=[^&]*|code=[^&]*") {$form.Close()}}
$web.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = $true
$web.Add_DocumentCompleted($DocComp)
$form.Controls.Add($web)
$form.Add_Shown({$form.Activate()})
$null = $form.ShowDialog()
$authCode = ([Web.HttpUtility]::ParseQueryString($web.Url.Query))["code"]

# Convert the oAuth2 code into a Token.
$body = ('grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri={0}&client_id={1}&client_secret={2}&code={3}&resource={4}' -f $redirectUri, $clientId, $clientSecretEncoded, $authCode, $resource)
$token = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token -Method Post -ContentType 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -Body $body -ErrorAction STOP).access_token

# URI which you wish to query 
$uri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/sendMail"

# Create Email JSON object
$body = 
@"
{
"message" : {
   "subject": "Fridge Robot",
   "body" : {
       "contentType": "Text",
       "content": "Coffee Sticker"
       },
  "toRecipients": [
   {
   "emailAddress" : {
       "address" : "jspitaleri@osugiving.com"
       }
   }
   ]
}
}
"@

# Invokes the request
Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $token"} -uri $uri -Method Post -ContentType application/json -Body $body
```

Comment: You want to switch to modern authentication? Check https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/tree/main/samples